# Branch Cut in Complex Antiderivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

I am reading James Ward Brown's *Complex Variables and Applications* and I am stuck on this problem.

**Problem:**

Show that $$\int_{-1}^{1} z^i dz=\frac{1+e^{-\pi}}{2}(1-i),$$ where the integrand denotes he principal branch $$z^i=exp(i\space Log\space z),\space\space (|z|>0,\space -\pi<Arg\space z<\pi)$$ of $z^i$ and where the path of integration is any contour from $z=-1$ to $z=1$ that, except for its end points, lies above the real axis.

The problem gives a hint that I should evaluate the antiderivative over the new branch where $arg\space z$ ranges from $-\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ to $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$.

**My questions are:**

1. Why is it necessary to change a branch, since the contour never crosses the branch cut of the principal branch of $z^i$?
2. I'd also like to know how the antiderivative is found, does it follow directly from real calculus to be $F(x)=\dfrac{z^{i+1}}{i+1}$, which does yield the correct result?

Comment: Do you mean "$-\pi < \arg z < \pi$"?  If so, why do you believe that the segment of the path of integration $[-1,0]$ is on this branch?

Comment: @EricTowers Since it's the principal branch, the A is capitalized. And this is where it confuses me: does it matter if the limits of integration is on the boundary of the branch? In other words, does it matter if the integral limits are indeed on the boundary of the branch, as long as the contour we are integrating on does not "cross" the boundary?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{Arg}(-1)$?  Is it in $(-\pi,\pi)$?  If not, what point of the path, which is not on the branch, is closest to $1$?  Would that not be the point at which the path (starting from $1$) leaves the branch?